# Помощь с многопоточностью на C# + GUI

Tags: c#

Я делаю не большую утилиту по скачиванию музыки из ВК. Использую библиотеки VK NET для C#. Проект WInForms

Собственно всё работает, НО...
На момент загрузки музыки "фризится" главная форма. У меня есть метод, который взаимодействует с минимальным набором классов (VK NET) + я добавляю ход загрузки (прогресс) в listBox. Всей загрузкой и прогрессом управляет цикл foreach (который находится в методе). System.Thread я использовать не могу, так как он требует "статику", а вся библиотека целиком динамическая + GUI так не работает.

Нашёл такую конструкцию с  await Task.Run:

```
public async void dwnMyPage()
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddAudioBypass();
        String alltracks = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Сколько у Вас всего треков?", "Введите число", "", 100, 100);
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(alltracks);
        listBox1.Items.Add("-> Идёт подготовка...");
        int i = 0;
        var audios = _api.Audio.Get(new AudioGetParams { Count = num });
        string res = null;
        //////////////////
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            foreach (var audio in audios)
            {
                i += 1;
                //artist = audio.Artist.ToString();
                // name = audio.Title.ToString();
                // number = i.ToString();
                //Thread LbWrite = new Thread(lbWrite);
                //LbWrite.Start();
                //Thread.Sleep(500);
                //MessageBox.Show(_api.Token);
                listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString() + ". " + audio.Artist.ToString() + " - " + audio.Title.ToString());
            //listBox1.GetSelected(listBox1.Items.Count - 1);//автопрокрутка
            ////listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            //listBox1.Refresh();

                try
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(audio.Url.ToString());
                    AudioDownloadExt.Download(audioCategory: _api.Audio, audio.Url, path + i.ToString() + ". " + audio.Artist.ToString() + " - " + audio.Title.ToString() + ".mp3");
                    listBox1.Items.Add("Загружено "+i.ToString() + ". " + audio.Artist.ToString() + " - " + audio.Title.ToString());
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
                {
                    i -= 1;
                    //listBox1.Refresh();
                    //Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    //listBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                   // listBox1.Items.Add("Трек не поддерживается!!!!");
                   // listBox1.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                   // listBox1.Refresh();
                    //Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                }
                catch (System.ArgumentNullException eeee)
                {
                    i -= 1;
                   // listBox1.Refresh();
                   // listBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    //Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                   // listBox1.Items.Add("Ошибка.");
                   // listBox1.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                   // listBox1.Refresh();
                    //Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                }

            }
        });
        // listBox1.Items.Add(res);
        // listBox1.Refresh();
        //////////////////

        listBox1.Items.Add(res);
        //listBox1.Refresh();
        //listBox1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        //listBox1.Items.Add("-> ЗАВЕРШЕНО!!!");
        //listBox1.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
        listBox1.Refresh();
    }//НЕ ДОРАБОТАНО!!!!!!!!!
```

Код пока жуткий... Всё работает, но вот прогресс мне никак не записать в listBox. Всё что относится к GUI элементу - вызывает ошибки, мол так нельзя.

Весь прогресс должен писаться из foreach и try ... catch

Что мне нужно поправить, исправить или дописать? Не совсем понимаю как с этим работать.

Comment: какие конкретно ошибки?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Comment: попробуйте юзать `lock` при работе с `listbox`

Comment: А это как? Просто заблочить сам listBox?

Comment: Нашёл только св-во Locked. Оно ничего не дало. Как я понимаю, ошибка при попытке влезть из другого потока в основной. Как-то же это обходится?

Comment: [вот похожий вопрос по блокировке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/395363/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-c)

Comment: либо использовать асинхронные методы для обработчиков, либо использовать контекст синхронизации https://habr.com/en/post/107583/

Answer (score 1):

О чудо! Меня осенило... Сам не понял, что сделал, но фриз пропал.

Вместо прямого обращения к listBox1 я использовал вот такую конструкцию:

```
listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { listBox1.Items.Add("Загружено "+res); }));
```

Что тут происходит - пока не знаю, но оно работает!!! Вызываю везде, где есть прогресс.

Comment: вот эта статья поможет понять что происходит https://habr.com/en/post/107583/